# Saving static files in redis session (Python flask)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, redis

I'm trying to build a machine learning web app where users can input the parameters and the predictions will be outputted as a .txt file. I'm also trying to use redis sessions as part of the web app so each users' .txt file will be different from each other.

I'm using

```
df.to_csv(filename.txt)
```

to transform my predictions dataframe into a .txt file. **Is it possible to save this .txt file in a redis session instead of saving it to the directory where the source code lies?**

Answer (score 0):

you need to serialize your .txt file but in my opinion I would not use Redis for such a task, maybe sqlite or directly in the server.

Comment: That solves one part of the problem. But I'm having a hard time converting the dataframe to .txt file directly into the redis session. I could potentially save the .txt file to source file directory, then save it into a redis session, then delete the .txt file from the source file directory. However, I'm trying to see if there any options to skip the step where I save the .txt file.